# Retrieving data from JSON column in SQL table

Tags: sql, json, vertica

I wonder how to retrieve data from json column in SQL. regexp_substr may work or [that one](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.2.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/Analytic/LAST_VALUEAnalytic.htm%3FTocPath%3DSQL%2520Reference%2520Manual%7CSQL%2520Functions%7CAnalytic%2520Functions%7C_____14) as its in Vertica table. I'm quite newbie and would be very grateful for any help which can help me to understand how to for example:

- find prem_amount for specific OFFICE_ID

Should I divide whole structure below on smaller pieces [like here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=teM0joVYN5Y) to understand structure?

```
[{"Constraint_a":{"match_all":false,"children":[{"match_all":true,"constraints":[{"operator":"GREATER_OR_EQUAL","property":"RATE","value":"0.850"},{"operator":"GREATER_OR_EQUAL","property":"CALLS_PER_HOUR","value":"1"},{"operator":"GREATER_OR_EQUAL","property":"IN_RATE","value":"1.000"}]}],"constraints":[]},"constraint_ids":["1"],"intervals":[{"end_offset":464400,"start_at":null,"start_offset":457200,"end_at":null}],"id":"1","OFFICE_ID":"1","content_hash_id":"1","inc_params":{"is_commissionable":false,"prem_amount":25.0,"fee":0.1},"filters":[],"visible_office_name":"site_trix","legacy_params":{}},{"Constraint_a":{"match_all":false,"children":[{"match_all":true,"constraints":[{"operator":"GREATER_OR_EQUAL","property":"RATE","value":"0.850"},{"operator":"GREATER_OR_EQUAL","property":"CALLS_PER_HOUR","value":"1"},{"operator":"GREATER_OR_EQUAL","property":"IN_RATE","value":"1.000"}]}],"constraints":[]},"constraint_ids":["2"],"intervals":[{"end_offset":550800,"start_at":null,"start_offset":543600,"end_at":null}],"id":"2","OFFICE_ID":"2","content_hash_id":"2","inc_params":{"is_commissionable":false,"prem_amount":25.0,"fee":0.1},"filters":[],"visible_office_name":"site_trix","legacy_params":{}},{"Constraint_a":{"match_all":false,"children":[{"match_all":true,"constraints":[{"operator":"GREATER_OR_EQUAL","property":"RATE","value":"0.850"},{"operator":"GREATER_OR_EQUAL","property":"CALLS_PER_HOUR","value":"1.5"},{"operator":"GREATER_OR_EQUAL","property":"IN_RATE","value":"1.000"}]}],"constraints":[]},"constraint_ids":["3"],"intervals":[{"end_offset":471600,"start_at":null,"start_offset":464400,"end_at":null}],"id":"3","OFFICE_ID":"3","content_hash_id":"3","inc_params":{"is_commissionable":false,"prem_amount":25.0,"fee":0.1},"filters":[],"visible_office_name":"site_trix","legacy_params":{}},{"Constraint_a":{"match_all":false,"children":[{"match_all":true,"constraints":[{"operator":"GREATER_OR_EQUAL","property":"RATE","value":"0.850"},{"operator":"GREATER_OR_EQUAL","property":"CALLS_PER_HOUR","value":"1.5"},{"operator":"GREATER_OR_EQUAL","property":"IN_RATE","value":"1.000"}]}],"constraints":[]},"constraint_ids":["4"],"intervals":[{"end_offset":558000,"start_at":null,"start_offset":550800,"end_at":null}],"id":"4","OFFICE_ID":"4","content_hash_id":"4","inc_params":{"is_commissionable":false,"prem_amount":25.0,"fee":0.1},"filters":[],"visible_office_name":"site_trix","legacy_params":{}},{"Constraint_a":{"match_all":false,"children":[{"match_all":true,"constraints":[{"operator":"GREATER_OR_EQUAL","property":"RATE","value":"0.850"},{"operator":"GREATER_OR_EQUAL","property":"CALLS_PER_HOUR","value":"1"},{"operator":"GREATER_OR_EQUAL","property":"IN_RATE","value":"1.000"}]}],"constraints":[]},"constraint_ids":["5"],"intervals":[{"end_offset":478800,"start_at":null,"start_offset":471600,"end_at":null}],"id":"5","OFFICE_ID":"5","content_hash_id":"5","inc_params":{"is_commissionable":false,"prem_amount":20.0,"fee":0.1},"filters":[],"visible_office_name":"site_trix","legacy_params":{}},{"Constraint_a":{"match_all":false,"children":[{"match_all":true,"constraints":[{"operator":"GREATER_OR_EQUAL","property":"RATE","value":"0.850"},{"operator":"GREATER_OR_EQUAL","property":"CALLS_PER_HOUR","value":"1"},{"operator":"GREATER_OR_EQUAL","property":"IN_RATE","value":"1.000"}]}],"constraints":[]},"constraint_ids":["6"],"intervals":[{"end_offset":565200,"start_at":null,"start_offset":558000,"end_at":null}],"id":"6","OFFICE_ID":"6","content_hash_id":"6","inc_params":{"is_commissionable":false,"prem_amount":20.0,"fee":0.1},"filters":[],"visible_office_name":"site_trix","legacy_params":{}},{"Constraint_a":{"match_all":false,"children":[{"match_all":true,"constraints":[{"operator":"GREATER_OR_EQUAL","property":"RATE","value":"0.850"},{"operator":"GREATER_OR_EQUAL","property":"CALLS_PER_HOUR","value":"1.5"},{"operator":"GREATER_OR_EQUAL","property":"IN_RATE","value":"1.000"}]}],"constraints":[]},"constraint_ids":["7"],"intervals":[{"end_offset":486000,"start_at":null,"start_offset":478800,"end_at":null}],"id":"7","OFFICE_ID":"7","content_hash_id":"7","inc_params":{"is_commissionable":false,"prem_amount":25.0,"fee":0.1},"filters":[],"visible_office_name":"site_trix","legacy_params":{}},{"Constraint_a":{"match_all":false,"children":[{"match_all":true,"constraints":[{"operator":"GREATER_OR_EQUAL","property":"RATE","value":"0.850"},{"operator":"GREATER_OR_EQUAL","property":"CALLS_PER_HOUR","value":"1.5"},{"operator":"GREATER_OR_EQUAL","property":"IN_RATE","value":"1.000"}]}],"constraints":[]},"constraint_ids":["8"],"intervals":[{"end_offset":572400,"start_at":null,"start_offset":565200,"end_at":null}],"id":"8","OFFICE_ID":"8","content_hash_id":"8","inc_params":{"is_commissionable":false,"prem_amount":25.0,"fee":0.1},"filters":[],"visible_office_name":"site_trix","legacy_params":{}},{"Constraint_a":{"match_all":false,"children":[{"match_all":true,"constraints":[{"operator":"GREATER_OR_EQUAL","property":"RATE","value":"0.850"},{"operator":"GREATER_OR_EQUAL","property":"CALLS_PER_HOUR","value":"1.5"},{"operator":"GREATER_OR_EQUAL","property":"IN_RATE","value":"1.000"}]}],"constraints":[]},"constraint_ids":["9"],"intervals":[{"end_offset":493200,"start_at":null,"start_offset":486000,"end_at":null}],"id":"9","OFFICE_ID":"9","content_hash_id":"9","inc_params":{"is_commissionable":false,"prem_amount":25.0,"fee":0.1},"filters":[],"visible_office_name":"site_trix","legacy_params":{}},{"Constraint_a":{"match_all":false,"children":[{"match_all":true,"constraints":[{"operator":"GREATER_OR_EQUAL","property":"RATE","value":"0.850"},{"operator":"GREATER_OR_EQUAL","property":"CALLS_PER_HOUR","value":"1.5"},{"operator":"GREATER_OR_EQUAL","property":"IN_RATE","value":"1.000"}]}],"constraints":[]},"constraint_ids":["10"],"intervals":[{"end_offset":579600,"start_at":null,"start_offset":572400,"end_at":null}],"id":"10","OFFICE_ID":"10","content_hash_id":"10","inc_params":{"is_commissionable":false,"prem_amount":25.0,"fee":0.1},"filters":[],"visible_office_name":"site_trix","legacy_params":{}},{"Constraint_a":{"match_all":false,"children":[{"match_all":true,"constraints":[{"operator":"GREATER_OR_EQUAL","property":"RATE","value":"0.850"},{"operator":"GREATER_OR_EQUAL","property":"CALLS_PER_HOUR","value":"1"},{"operator":"GREATER_OR_EQUAL","property":"IN_RATE","value":"1.000"}]}],"constraints":[]},"constraint_ids":["11"],"intervals":[{"end_offset":500400,"start_at":null,"start_offset":493200,"end_at":null}],"id":"11","OFFICE_ID":"11","content_hash_id":"11","inc_params":{"is_commissionable":false,"prem_amount":20.0,"fee":0.1},"filters":[],"visible_office_name":"site_trix","legacy_params":{}},{"Constraint_a":{"match_all":false,"children":[{"match_all":true,"constraints":[{"operator":"GREATER_OR_EQUAL","property":"RATE","value":"0.850"},{"operator":"GREATER_OR_EQUAL","property":"CALLS_PER_HOUR","value":"1"},{"operator":"GREATER_OR_EQUAL","property":"IN_RATE","value":"1.000"}]}],"constraints":[]},"constraint_ids":["12"],"intervals":[{"end_offset":586800,"start_at":null,"start_offset":579600,"end_at":null}],"id":"12","OFFICE_ID":"12","content_hash_id":"12","inc_params":{"is_commissionable":false,"prem_amount":20.0,"fee":0.1},"filters":[],"visible_office_name":"site_trix","legacy_params":{}}]
```

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 1):

The json you provided here is malformed. You can quickly check by using an online json validator. There are several websites out there you can use.
For example: [JSON Formatter](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)

More information on querying json data can be found here: [JSON data in SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 1):

How did you get the JSON data into Vertica?  Are you putting it into a VARCHAR?  That's not ideal because you can't easily validate it (as demonstrated by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52093609/922300)) or extract values from it.  Instead, you can load JSON data using the [FJSONParser](https://my.vertica.com/docs/9.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/FlexTables/FJSONPARSERreference.htm).  For example:

```
vsql> create table super(age int, name varchar);

vsql> copy super from stdin parser fjsonparser();
Enter data to be copied followed by a newline.
End with a backslash and a period on a line by itself.
>> {"age": 5, "name": "Tim"}
>>  {"age": 3}
>>  {"name": "Fred"}
>>  {"name": "Bob", "age": 10}
>> \.

vsql> select * from super;
 age | name
-----+------
     | Fred
  10 | Bob
   5 | Tim
   3 |
(4 rows)
```

Obviously you won't be typing your JSON on STDIN; that's just the example in the documentation.  You can load from a JSON file like this:

```
vsql> COPY SE.PostLinks FROM '"$loaddir"/PostLinks.json' PARSER fjsonparser();
```

(Guess what data I was experimenting with. :-) )